# Ubuntu on Tablets: Installing Software without the Store?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

When Ubuntu is run on a tablet, will it be possible to install software directly, i.e. without going through your store or will installation of third party be locked down to the store like with Apples iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to find and install apps from the Dash, rather than a separate app store.  There are no plans to prevent you from manually installing software packages, though the exact package format and tools for doing so are still being worked out.